# adding to favourites and storing in another activity android

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity

This is my main code, where I use a togglebutton and once heart button is clicked, the heart icon would change to black but I'm struggling to view favourites in another activity:

```
toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recipe Added To Favourites", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecipeDetails.this, FavViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("favlist", getIntent().getStringExtra("Recipe Name"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
                // The toggle is disabled
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Recipe Removed From Favourites", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            saveState(isChecked);
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

This is to get the name of the recipe:

```
if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null){
        displayRecipe(getIntent().getStringExtra("Recipe Name"));
    }
```

And this is my FavViewActivity:

```
public class FavViewActivity extends RecipeDetails {
private ListView lv = null;
private ArrayList<String> favList = null;
private ArrayList<String> favourites = null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favourites);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, favourites);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_fav);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (getIntent().getExtras()!=null) {
        favList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("favlist");
        for (String item : favList) {
            favourites.add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why the Firebase tag?

Comment: To retrieve the name of the recipe which is stored in firebase